# Connection refused by Spring boot app running in different docker container

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker

I have three apps running in 3 containers on the same host.

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                       COMMAND               PORTS                    

3f938111c1bf    registration   "java -jar registration.jar"       0.0.0.0:8030->8030/tcp  
cb9c4782194e    security       "java -jar security.jar"           0.0.0.0:8020->8020/tcp  
60005507a246    main           "java -jar main.jar"               0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

I am able to access an endpoint of the security app from main app using an Ajax request.

The registration app calls an endpoint of security app from a java method using a RestTemplate object. This call is refused by the security app as follows.

```
I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8020/security/register": Connect to localhost:8020 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8020 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I am not able to identify the issue. **Note that this call is working perfectly fine when I run these apps locally through eclipse.**

I am very new to the dockers. Is there a possibility that I am missing out something? Any leads would be helpful.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you work with docker containers/images so you need to set your configurations on them. So you must change localhost to your container name. For example:

```
 http://localhost:8020/security/register

 http://authentication:8020/security/register
```

Comment: Cool! :) @AbhinavPrakash